# Multiple choice values and more than 1 restriction

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Got this XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="equipos.xsl"?>
<equipos>
    <equipo nombre="Los paellas" personas="2"/>
    <equipo nombre="Los arrocitos" personas="13"/>
    <equipo nombre="Los gambas" personas="6"/>
    <equipo nombre="Los mejillones" personas="3"/>
    <equipo nombre="Los garrofones" personas="17"/>
    <equipo nombre="Los limones" personas="7"/>
</equipos>
```

Applying an XSLT the output must be:

- attribute "personas" overrided with an attribute called "categoria"
- "categoria" must have valor 1 if personas < 5
- "categoria" must have valor 2 if personas is BETWEEN 5 and 10
- "categoria" must have valor 3 if personas > 10

This is my XSLT for now, but i dont find the way to get the 3rd condition for "categoria" on choose...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="equipos">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="equipo">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="nombre">
            <xsl:value-of select="@nombre"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="categoria">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="@personas &lt; 5">
                    <xsl:text>1</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:text>2</xsl:text>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have as many `when` elements as you like inside the `choose`:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="@personas &lt; 5">
        <xsl:text>1</xsl:text>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="@personas &lt;= 10">
        <xsl:text>2</xsl:text>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:text>3</xsl:text>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

A `choose` takes the first matching `when` branch, so you don't need to check for `>=5` in the second branch - you already know this because you didn't take the first one.

But for future reference, a more idiomatic XSLT way to approach this might be to use matching templates instead of a `choose` construct:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <!-- copy everything unchanged except when overridden -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@personas[. &lt; 5]" priority="10">
    <xsl:attribute name="categoria">1</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@personas[. &lt;= 10]" priority="9">
    <xsl:attribute name="categoria">2</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@personas" priority="8">
    <xsl:attribute name="categoria">3</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here we need the explicit priorities because the patterns `@personas[. &lt; 5]` and `@personas[. &lt;= 10]` are considered equally specific by default.